# Forcibly create directory hard link(s)?

Tags: shell, hard-link, ln

I understand the reasoning why nearly every unix version doesn't allow hard-linking of directories (in fact HFS+ on OS X is the only one I know, but even that isn't made easy to do yourself). However, all file-systems in theory support hard-linked directories, as all directories contain at least one extra hard-link to itself, plus extra hard-links in sub-directories pointing back to their parent.

Now, I realise that hard-linking can be dangerous if misused, as it can create cyclical structures that few programs will check for, and thus become stuck in an infinite loop. However, I was hoping to use hard-links to create a Time Machine style backup that can work for any unix. I don't believe that this kind of structure would be dangerous, as the links simply point to previous backups; there should be no risk of cyclical linking. In my case I'm currently just using rsync to create hard-links to existing files, but this slow and wasteful, particularly with very large backups and especially if I already know which directories are unchanged.

With this in mind, is there any way to force the creation of directory hard-links on unix variants? `ln` is presumably no good as this is the place that many unix flavours put their restricts upon in order to prevent hard-linking directories, and `ln` versions that support hard-linked directories specifically state that the operation is likely to fail. But for someone who knows the risks, and knows that their use-case is safe, is there any way to actually create the link anyway? Ideally for a shell script, but if I need to compile a small program to do it then I suppose I could.

Comment: Short answer: No. The reason it fails is the kernel prohibits it.

Comment: Don't do it as anything other than an intellectual curiosity. You will break the filesystem.

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is a revision control system: e.g. mercurial or sub-version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do this. If you want to have a backup system using hard links to save space, better to use rsync with `--link-dest`, which will hard link *files* appropriately to save space, without causing the problems that this causes (that is, hard linking between directories is a corruption of the filesystem, and will cause it to report wrong inode counts + fail fsck + generally have unknown semantics due to not being a DAG).

Comment: Which will cause it to fail `fsck`. `Pass 2: Checking directory structure`
`Entry 'bar' in / (2) is a link to directory /foo (12).`
`Clear<y>? ` Also leaves a wrong ref count in the inode (later fsck message)

Comment: @derobert I don't know what you were expecting...

Comment: Well, I wasn't expecting the wrong inode count. But the point is, OP actually wants to *use* this, not just do it as an intellectual curiosity. And this is clearly not a sane backup strategy. Or even half-sane. So that comment is to make sure OP is aware of that.

Comment: @derobert Ah, my eyes skipped to "for someone who knows the risks" and eschewed the rest, so I didn't see what they were actually planning to do with it. Yes, in which case, basically don't do it. I added an alternative.

Comment: Errrr... From the question: "In my case I'm currently just using rsync to create hard-links to existing files, but this slow and wasteful, particularly with very large backups and especially if I already know which directories are unchanged." Time for more coffee, I think.

Comment: @derobert It's always time for more coffee! :-)

Comment: +1 for `rsync --link-dest`, which is exactly the right solution for this backup scenario.

Comment: Apologies for the long delay in marking an answer, and thanks to all the responses! For those interested I decided to use a custom solution with symbolic links instead; it's a much bigger headache to manage since I have to swap links for their targets when it comes time to prune old backups, plus other fiddling, but when I know a folder hasn't changed it is *much* faster on slower devices (like ARM NASes) where `rsync --link-dest` can take a long time with 100,000+ files.

Comment: Even if there were no problems, I do not think it would even work. You create a hard link to a directory, as a backup. Then you change a file in the original, and both are changed.

Comment: A directory hierarchy with hard links is still a DAG. You mean not a tree?

Comment: @immibis If hard linking a directory was possible, it would be possible to create an structure which is not a DAG as there would no longer be a guarantee of finitude.

Answer (score 3):

If you are unable to use `debugfs` interactively, you can pipe to it and use
`sed` to remove the prompt and echoed-back command from its output.

```
echo 'link /foo /bar' | debugfs -w [device] | sed '$s/debugfs:  $//' | sed '1d'
```

Comment: AFAIK, `debugfs` is not a utility available on "every Unix".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `debugfs` to do this. With the filesystem not mounted, do `debugfs -w /dev/device_name`. Then, at the debugfs prompt, use the `link` command the same way you would use `ln` if hard links to directories were normally possible. (e.g. `link /original_dir /new_link`) The `link` command in debugfs, unlike `ln` and the `link` system call, allows hard links to directories to be created. Once you're done, just type `quit`.

However, as other people have mentioned, **DO NOT** actually do this. It will cause problems. I'm just saying this because you asked how to forcibly create a directory hard link, and that's how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Directories ***should never*** have extra hard links to them. Sure, you can create them, but that is a *serious* corruption of the filesystem.

The reason is that directories must always form a tree structure, else it is impossible to traverse them sanely to clean up. Yes, it will work fine for now. But the next time you have to run fsck(8) for any reason, it probably won't do its work, or at best just delete one of the spurious links.

No, this is not theory. A Ultrix system long ago here got a few directories hardlinked by some glitch. Cleaning that up by editing the filessytem was no fun.

Comment: It should still be a tree-structure, for example `/Backups/2013-05-10/foo` and `/Backups/2013-05-11/foo` pointing to the same inode. While things like searches may traverse both not recognising they're the same, it shouldn't cause any issues otherwise, though I suppose unix isn't equipped to delete hard-linked directories either (rm -R would delete the contents of both directories for example).

Comment: @Haravikk, that isn't a tree, it's a DAG. And it has to be strictly a tree.

Comment: Even so, the only reasons that seem to be against doing it are that unix programs (such as `fsck`) wouldn't support it properly, and that you can create loops. But assuming I could simply ignore links that `fsck` doesn't like, rather than letting it "fix" them, and that I know my structure couldn't result in loops, then I don't see any reason not to do it. As I say, Time Machine does this and it works extremely well because of there is no chance of looping.